# String variables becomes null outside setOnClickListener() function

Tags: android, string, android-studio

I have a simple android app in which I want to get the user input (String). So I have an "EditText" box and an "Enter" button. When the user types something and hits Enter, I am trying to display that text and it works as long as I do all that inside the 'setOnClickListener()' function. The string variables becomes null outside the function. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button hitButton;
 EditText userInput;
 String myVariable;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    hitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
          myVariable= userInput.getText().toString();

       }
    });

     TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     textView.setText(myVariable); // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
     // IT DISPLAYS NULL WHICH MEANS THAT String myVariable = null
     }
  }
```

If I put TextView.setText(myVariable) inside the setOnClickListener function then it works perfectly but outside the function, myVariable becomes null. And I need to user that variable outside the function.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `myVariable` is only initialized after the `onClickListener` is called, so this is normal.

Comment: onClick is the method which will trigger only when you click button. So if your textView needs to get value updated. It should be inside onClick than outside

Comment: It isn't that it become's null, it is that you are setting the value in your TextView before you ever are able to actually click the button and set the input to myVariable. Move the `textView.setText(myVariable); ` portion inside of the onClickListener

Comment: Use `textView.setText(myVariable);` line inside `onClick ` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it outside the onClick method, Use SharedPreferences for this like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button hitButton;
 EditText userInput;
 String myVariable;
 public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
 public static final String KEY = "Key";
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);        

    hitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
          myVariable= userInput.getText().toString();

          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
          editor.putString(KEY, myVariable);
          editor.commit();
       }
    });

     TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     textView.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(KEY, null)); // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
     // IT DISPLAYS NULL WHICH MEANS THAT String myVariable = null
     }
  }
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

The method onCreate is called once when your Activity launches. So this is where you want to initialise your TextView like you do:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

But in order to set the value of the variable myVariable when the user clicks the button and set the text of your TextView, you have to call the setText method of your TextView inside the onClick method.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
          userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
          myVariable= userInput.getText().toString();
          textView.setText(myVariable);    
       }
```

On user's click the variable myVariable is set and it is available outside the function as well, because you have declare it on top.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is the method which will trigger only when you click button.

So if your `textView` needs to get value updated when clicking button, It should be inside `onClick` than outside like this.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
          userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
          myVariable= userInput.getText().toString();
          textView.setText(myVariable);    
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete Stallion's answer,

```
textView.setText(myVariable);
```

as you put it, is currently executed at the creation of your activity, as it is located in the `onCreate` method (which is why `myVariable` is still `null`) but never again after.

Answer (score 0):

IT DISPLAYS NULL WHICH MEANS THAT String myVariable = null , its because you try to settext with a null variable only updated when onClick triggered. 
You have to do this to make it work : 
Declare and instantiate your EditText userIput outside your onclick method just after you instantiate your button and give your myVariable a default value "" in declaration .