# How to get the actual width of view in values in any adapter class if it is define as match parent in xml file in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, width, layoutparams

How can I get width in values for any layout or card view inside an adapter class?
I have a layout file which I am using for a custom adapter class, where I had taken a view that is card view and given width as match parent now in adapter class I want card view width in values.
I have tried multiple methods, for example, using post method with card view or view tree observer.

```
CardView mCardView;
int width=0;
int rootWidth,rootHeight;
mCardView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.mCardView);

// Method in Recyclerview Adapter Class
public void onBindHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    // using viewtreeobserver to get width of view 
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mCardView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    rootHeight = mCardView.getHeight();
                    rootWidth = mCardView.getWidth();
                }
            });
    }

    //Another method tried to get the width of the view 

    mCardView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rootHeight = mCardView.getHeight();
            rootWidth = mCardView.getWidth();
        }
    });

     width = rootWidth;  //always return 0 in both th cases

}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve by getting match parent width?

Comment: I just want its actual width in values for further conversion in my code.

Comment: sir it's not proper way cause it gives wrong details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason you're getting null value.

For this i'll provide example :

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.card?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                holder.card?.getViewTreeObserver()?.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                Log.e("widths", holder.card?.measuredWidth.toString())
            }
        })
        Log.e("text","i am here")
    }
```

Output of this code is :

```
E/text: i am here
E/text: i am here
E/widths: 1080
E/widths: 1080
```

as per example you can see my **text** `Log` runs before getting width. The reason behind is my `bindviewholder` is in progress to set the data to view. After process complete it will provide proper value of my `width`.

Same issue happening with you. as you commented you're values return 0 outside function. it because outside the function your `onbindviewholder` in process.

Better method for you're problem is

You can use **SharedPreferences** to store your width in Local. 
For explanation you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37164899/10182897) answer he provided proper way to do it.

If there's anything i can help just comment your problem

Answer (score -1):

You can get/set any layout parameter programmatically  `getLayoutParams()` method of any view. for example if you want height then you can use `iv.getLayoutParams().height`

Reference of above ans. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams